# "Unsplit" article pages on the web

Tags: internet, web

Many articles on the net are split up into multiple pages (commonly called "pagination").  However, this can be quite annoying to read - I would rather have the whole article on my screen at once.  In this way, I would be able to scroll down to view the whole article rather than click through multiple pages.

I know that some sites provide a "Print View" option, and some sites do allow you to view all text on one page, but what can I do about sites that don't support this? Is there an add-on for my browser that I can use to show the whole article on one page?

For an example of what I am talking about, see [this tutorial](http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/ss/forms.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AutoPager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4925) also a Firefox add-on

[image]

> The AutoPager Firefox extension
>   automatically loads the next page of a
>   site inline when you reach the end of
>   the current page for infinite
>   scrolling of content.  It includes a
>   adblock similar features to allow you
>   filter out the ads from the contents
>   in the loaded page contents.
>
> It works well with most of the
>   greasemonkey scripts. By default
>   AutoPager works with a ton of sites,
>   including Lifehacker, the New York
>   Times, Digg, and, of course, Google.
>   If you want to add your own custom
>   autopaging to unsupported sites, the
>   site wizard feature makes it easy
>   (first pick the Next link, then pick
>   only the content you want loaded. The
>   site workshop provide more features
>   like auto discovery the links and
>   content.
>
> It's configuration is base on XPath.
>   You can find there is a built in
>   function to create a XPath by click
>   some links on the pages. This
>   extension will import online
>   configuration from this sources,these
>   configurations includes support for
>   some widely used sites and some
>   general support for forums.

Comment: AutoPager also has a Next link problem, it will always refer to the page after the original page. Don't know why that is

Answer (score 0):

[PageZipper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11284/) add-on for Firefox is what you're after.

Comment: Should note that `PageZipper 0.4` is an experimental addon.

Comment: It also seems to be biased towards a `Next` link (I was wondering how this was scripted, having tried this once some years back on Unix).