# How to stitch (paged) web pages together into one page for printing

Tags: printing, web

Is there a way to stitch (paged) web pages together?

For example, I want to print out [this thread](http://www.healthboards.com/boards/printthread.php?t=296667&pp=20), but it is divided into 10 sections;
How can I join them together to make printing easier and more efficient?

I would prefer a quick web-based solution, but simple off-line tools would also be acceptable (I have downloaded each section and manually merged the files into one html file, before...)

**Edit:** I forgot to mention I use Opera on Vista Enterprise

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/22124/unsplit-article-pages-on-the-web

Comment: I have compared both questions and there is one fundamental difference between the two, one, the solution for the possible duplicate is for Firefox only, and two this post refers to *printing* whereas as the possible duplicate refers to *viewing*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to bother with addons, you can try and see if there is a version of the site that will dump out everything for a print version.

For most forums, there is often a lofi version which will remove the paging and display the entire thread on the one page. The trick is to find the page/directory for that particular forum software.

In your case, HealthBoards is running on vBulletin, and the lofi path to that is `/archive/`. This should be the new path after the directory to the boards themselves and will look like this:

> [http://www.healthboards.com/boards/archive/index.php](http://www.healthboards.com/boards/archive/)

From there you can navigate back to the thread and see all the posts on a single page.

#### The quick grab version of a vBulletin thread:

The original thread is here:

> http://www.healthboards.com/boards/showthread.php?t=296667

Quick way is to grab that value just after the `t=` (and before the next ampersand (`&`) in the URL) and replace as necessary in the below:

> http://www.healthboards.com/boards/archive/index.php/t-296667.html

Comment: Hey, that suits my needs very well for this case. I thought the "printable" version was the best lofi version available. If no one comes up with a generalized solution, I will accept this answer.

Comment: A generalised solution being better, but thought that this method might help in similar cases.

Comment: Now that is slick, echo.

Comment: Answer accepted, although I had problems printing this version out! (Need to select all, print selection in IE)

Comment: What problem did you have?

Comment: Good specific solution to the OP's site, but not as relevant as other answers to the general question (and title of the page).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Firefox I suggest the [AutoPager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4925) extension. It will go through all the pages and combine them into a single large page, then you can just print out the whole page its created for you.

For most sites it can automatically join the separate pages into a single page, but for some you have to tell it where the links are.

Answer (score 2):

this solution works for unix, but i'm sure you can find equivalents for vista.

first, use wget to download the files:

```
wget -nd -k -p "http://www.healthboards.com/boards/printthread.php?t=296667&pp=20&page="{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} --wait 5
```

then use cat to concatenate them. i don't know the windows equivalent of this command, but there surely must be one:

```
cat "printthread.php?t=296667&pp=20&page="* > hello.html
```

the file hello.html will be one big file with all the thread pages. you might get annoyed by the fact that all the pages have that vbulletin logo though!

edit: here is [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for windows. of course, you could use some other download manager

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows) is how to concatenate files on windows.

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial apps out there if you don't mind spending some money. I've used ClickBook from [BlueSquirrel](http://www.bluesquirrel.com) which, among other things, can stich together multiple printouts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Microsoft Excel (if you have one :) )
It has the functionality to make  web queries  (Menu: Data > Import External Data > Web Query)

I recorded VB macros and made some changes, so you can add addresses to the first Sheet, 
like: (each address is in next cell)

http://www.healthboards.com/boards/printthread.php?t=296667&pp=20&page=1 
............................................./boards/printthread.php?t=296667&pp=20&page=2
............................................./boards/printthread.php?t=296667&pp=20&page=3

and then run this macros and get result.
It helped me.

macros:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro

'
Dim url As String
Dim count As Integer

Dim resaultSheet As String
Dim adressesSheet As String

  adressesSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
  resaultSheet = Sheets.Add().Name

Sheets(adressesSheet).Select
Sheets(adressesSheet).Cells(1, 1).Select

ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select

count = ActiveCell.Row

Sheets(resaultSheet).Select
Sheets(resaultSheet).Cells(1, 1).Select

For i = 1 To count

 url = "URL;" + Sheets(adressesSheet).Cells(i, 1)


 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        url, Destination _
        :=ActiveCell)
        .Name = "name"
         .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = False
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
        .WebDisableRedirections = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

       ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1).Select

Next i


End Sub
```