# firefox add on that let me continuously read the pages of forum or search results

Tags: firefox, forum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Unsplit” article pages on the web](https://superuser.com/questions/22124/unsplit-article-pages-on-the-web)

i once had an add on on firefox that let me go to the next page in forum or search results without clicking on the page number but by going to the bottom of the page. What is this called?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/22124/unsplit-article-pages-on-the-web

Comment: Yes, and it includes the autopager addon, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4925 , which I was going to post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**[Thread Views](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/9743)** - Adds toolbar buttons to switch between all threads and threads with unread.

but it's no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for forums but, since you also mentioned search results, [CustomizeGoogle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/743) is an extension that can be configured to fetch more results in a Google search simply by scrolling to the bottom of the page.  It can actually do a lot more than just that.

Answer (score 0):

"SMARTER FOX" does exacly that
 but just now, looking for it again, sombody is saying that it is a privacy risk... i´m thinking on uninstalling it.